# How to achieve regression model without underfitting or overfitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have my university project and i'm given a `dataset` which almost all features have a very weak (only 1 feature has moderate correlation with the target) correlation with the target. It's distribution is not normal too. I already tried to apply simple model linear regression it caused `underfitting`, then i applied `simple random forest regressor` but it caused `overfitting` but when i applied `random forest regressor` with optimization with `randomsearchcv` it took time so long. Is there any way to get decent model with not-so-good `dataset` without underfitting or overfitting? or it's just not possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to be blunt, if you could fit a model without underfitting or overfitting you would have solved AI completely.

Some suggestions, though:

#### Overfitting on random forests

- Personally, I'd try to hack this route since you mention that your data is not strongly correlated. It's typically easier to fix overfitting than underfitting so that helps, too.
- Try looking at your tree outputs. If you are using `python`, `sci-kit learn`'s `export_graphviz` can be helpful.
- Try reducing the maximum depth of the trees.
- Try increasing the maximum number of a samples a tree must have in order to split (or similarly, the minimum number of samples a leaf should have).
- Try increasing the number of trees in the RF.

#### Underfitting on linear regression

- Add more parameters. If you have variables a, b, ... etc. adding their polynomial features, i.e. a^2, a^3 ... b^2, b^3 ... etc. may help. If you add enough polynomial features you should be able to overfit -- although that doesn't necessarily mean it will have a good fit on the train set (RMSE value).
- Try plotting some of the variables against the value to predict (y). Perhaps you may be able to see a non-linear pattern (i.e. a logarithmic relationship).
- Do you know anything about the data? Perhaps a variable that is the multiple, or the division between two variables may be a good indicator.
- If you are regularizing (or if the software is automatically applying) your regression, try reducing the regularization parameter.

Comment: is there any way i could find best parameter for my RF without RandomSearchCV?

Comment: @potatostudent Yes, but it's very difficult to know without what your data is like. I would suggest interpreting your data a little bit, looking at some of the tree outputs of the RF, to decide what kind of hyperparameters would be appropriate for testing.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me, I'm sorry, let's say i have interpreted my data and know the the tree ouputs of the RF, how can i decide appropriate hyperparameter for that? do you know any reading that could help me to understand deciding appropriate hyperparameter based on the tree outputs? Thank you so much

Comment: There's much information on Google. [This](https://www.kaggle.com/general/4092) and [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/06/tuning-random-forest-model/) seem to be good places to start. Good luck!